# Mapbox not fully rendering on android build (Quasar Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, mapbox, quasar

On the quasar dev version of our app mapbox uses the devices location and renders a map properly. However when running the android version only the back layer panel and buttons display. The current model is built with vue(using Quasar) being run through cordova. to test navigate to the cordova folder and run cordova emulate android, log in with user@gmail.com 123abc, click through any of the response tokens say fire building fire. Then the application should get your location and center a rendered map on you. Any help on this would be truly lifesaving!!!
Repo link;
https://github.com/Screen-Art-Studios/Total-Response-Android